# set size of backgroundimage on viewport minus navbar

Tags: css, height, navbar, viewport

can you tell me, how i can set the height of a backgroundimage depending on viewportsize and the height of navbar. The backgroundimage should fit complete screen from bot until the navbar begins. Navbar is fixed on top, it is a landing page. If I scroll down, backgroundimage should be stop exactly when navbar begins. I hope, you guys know, what i try to explain. Do you have any idea, how to reach that.

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect fit for `vh` (viewport height) unit and css `calc()` method to work together. I made an example for you.

The viewport height unit works roughly the same as `%` but `1vh` is 1/100th of the viewport height and `100vh` is 100/100 of the height. *(yes, there also is a vw unit!)*

The `calc()` function is used to subtract the height of the navigation bar and the background container.

```css
/* Answer */

.backgroundImage {
  position: absolute;
  height: calc(100vh - 30px); /* you can use calc() function. */
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://placehold.it/2000x2000');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* additional styling */

body {
  background: lightblue;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
  height: 30px;
}



main {
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 400px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="backgroundImage"></div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```